# Fourier transform theorem proof help

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm learning Fourier analysis by
Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi
and stuck on this step on the page 206. How to prove that $\hat{f}( s\gamma ) e^{2\pi ix\cdot \gamma s}$ is an even function so that we could split and double the integral. Or maybe these halves are equal for another reason?

$\hat{f}$ - Fourier transform of $f$

[image]